# Отделение запятой части текста

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я грамматически оформил данное предложение:
1. Нужна ли запятая перед словом ***разбилось***?
2. Уместно ли здесь тире?

***Всё, что я думал и представлял об эмоциональной связи разбилось и ушло ― всё это было не тем.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. **Всё, что я думал и представлял об эмоциональной связи, разбилось и ушло ― всё это было не тем.**

Бессоюзная связь обозначена тире, которое указывает на взаимообусловленность первой и второй части (причинно-следственные отношения).

Придаточное изъяснительное с союзом ЧТО обособляется запятыми.

Вариант 2. **Всё, что я думал и представлял об эмоциональной связи, разбилось и ушло, всё это было не тем.**

Запятая вместо тире, простое распространение.

Интонация двух вариантов различна.